# Promise usage inside node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Im new to promise topic and I wonder if I write this following code
as it should be .

We are using at our project **bluebird**

This is the code:

```
var start = function (destination ){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(destination, function (err, values) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                values.reverse();
                var flag = true;
                values.forEach(function (file) {
                    if (flag) {
                        flag = false;
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        fs.unlink(destination + '/' + file, function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Error ' + err);
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('sucess ' + dest + '/' + file);
                                resolve();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: a Promise can only be resolved/rejected once - any subsequent resolve/reject calls are ignored - your code has a loop, each loop will either resolve or reject the Promise, anything but the first loop is ignored (as far as the promise is concerned) - so, no, your code is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy there tiger, you're working way harder than you need to.

Your logic is:

1. Read all the files in destination
2. Reverse them
3. Save the last file and don't unlink it.
4. Unlink all the other files

Here's an alternative answer to mmm's using [coroutines](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) and bluebird:

```
let Promise = require("bluebird");
let fs = require("fs");
Promise.promisifyAll("fs");

const start = Promise.coroutine(function* (destination) { 
    let files = yield fs.readdirAsync(destination); // 1. read files
    files = files.reverse(); 2. reverse them
    files.shift(); // 3. except the first one
    yield Promise.map(files, f => fs.unlinkAsync(`${destination}/${f}`)); 4. unlink
});
```

Or, possibly more elegantly:

```
const start = Promise.coroutine(function* (destination) { 
    let files = yield fs.readdirAsync(destination);
    files.pop();
    yield Promise.map(files, f => fs.unlinkAsync(`${destination}/${f}`));
});
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin ,Thank you! 3  questions :)  1. I use bluebird version2.9...so I dont think I can use it "coroutine" (cannot upgrade currenlty...) 2. what about the error handling ? 3. How should I use it in older version of node (es5..) Thank you voted up!

Comment: 1) Yes you can, 2) Catch when you need to, this is like synchronous code - it propagates on error to the closest `.catch` (or try/catch inside coroutine). 3) What version? If it's above 0.10 you can `--harmony-generators`.

Answer (score 1):

In bluebird, using `new Promise` is an anti-pattern and should be avoided if possible. Instead, you would use bluebird's [`promisifyAll()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) method to [promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) `fs` and take that as a starting point.

For example:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var start = function (destination ) {
    return fs.readdirAsync(destination)
        .then(values => values.reverse()) // or `.call("reverse")`
        .then(values => {
            // your logic
        }); // .catch(err => { ... }); // by default bluebird logs errors to the console
};
```

In your further logic you are trying to fulfill or reject the promise multiple times, which can't be done - only the first call to `resolve/reject` will be taken into consideration here. I think you want to delete all but the latest file. So something like

```
var start = function (destination ) {
    return fs.readdirAsync(destination)
        .then(values => values.reverse())
        .then(files => {
            files.shift();
            return files;
        })
        .map(file => fs.unlinkAsync(`${destination}/${file}`))
        .then(success => {
            console.log(success) // will hold an array of success messages
            return success;
        });
};
```

Will do what you want, like it should be done.

---

If you're using node earlier than v4 or are unfamiliar with es6, here's the es5 version:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var start = function start(destination) {
    return fs.readdirAsync(destination).then(function (values) {
        return values.reverse();
    }).then(function (files) {
        files.shift();
        return files;
    }).map(function (file) {
        return fs.unlinkAsync(destination + '/' + file);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BenjaminGruenbaum ! Should we change `.then(values => values.reverse())` to `call("reverse")` in the code?

Comment: Either is fine, I think it's fine the way it is.